# Saving Hawtio Jolokia parameters in the remote window

Tags: hawtio

Is there any way to save JMX remote properties in Hawtio probably per user-wise or by connection name?

Currently the issue is - I need to provide the hostname,port, etc always manually whenever I start a new instance of Hawtio.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHsLs.png)

Comment: Yeah i think they can be provided in the uri as query parameters, you can maybe try to use some browser inspect tool that can capture all urls and then you can see what the url is when you press that form button, and then build that url yourself

Answer (score 1):

This scenario can be achieved by using remote connection save option.